# Count unique values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
value1-------value2------time
1            2           1440273663
1            1           1440273699
2            3           1448293763
1            1           1440273663
3            2           1440273693
```

And I want to count the number of unique values in column 1. 
For this example table, this would be 3.

Comment: Take a look at the manual.

Comment: @Strawberry I did google this, with no results. Nothing for this phrase in this manual. According to Rahul Tripathi's answer, MySQL has no such function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like below for a table named `t` with column `value1`

```
select count(distinct value1) from t;
```

Here's a demo sql fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b903/1

Answer (score 2):

Use `distinct`:

```
Select count(distinct value1) from table
```